# Rigidbody Velocity Messing Up Physics UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, velocity

I am trying to move my player by using rigidbody.velocity:

```
rigidbod.velocity = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * maxSpeed, rigidbod.velocity.y);
```

the problem is, this messes up of my explosion code. The character is supposed to be knocked back when near an explosion. I know why it happens; if the player is still, the rigidbody's X velocity would be returned as 0, meaning any outside forces pushing the player along the X axis would counteract this. So when I add the explosion, the player cuts to his new position a few units away. It looks very unnatural and jerky, as he should be pushed back, but his code is telling him to be still unless a key is pressed. I'm posting this to see if there's any way I can re-write this code to be able to move the player while being pushed correctly from outside forces. I heard that AddForce works, but when I used it, my player's velocity constantly increased. He is wither way too fast or way too slow. Any ideas on how I can get this to work? I tried adding rigidbody.velocity.x after where it says 'maxspeed' hoping that it would allow outside force input, and it works, but it messes up the movement code, making him go way too fast. I can't seem to get both the explosions and the movement code to work correctly at the same time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which is exactly why in the Unity docs they explicitly state:

> In most cases you should not modify the velocity directly, as this can
>   result in unrealistic behaviour.

instead of modifying the velocity directly, you should be using an `AddForce(..)`

```
Vector2 force = new Vector2 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * maxSpeed, 0f);
rigidbody.AddForce(force);

//or if in update:
rigidbody.AddForce(force * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Thats exactly why you have to include the `* Time.deltaTime` in the `AddForce(...)` anytime you are compounding them over multiple frames as i stated

Comment: I'm not sure if you get what I'm saying. I acknoledged this in what I wrote. The problem with AddForce is that the velocity of my player will constantly increase. The player doesn't reach a maximum velocity. Thus, the player goes crazy fast if holding a single direction. I stated that in what I wrote. I really appreciate you trying to help, but this isn't really what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway! @LOLslowSTir

Comment: You can use the velocity in a condition. `if(velocity.x < maxSpeed) AddForce(force * Time.deltaTime)`. Force wont be added if too fast but wont mess with explosion.

Comment: If he wants it like that, he can manipulate the `velocity` directly, but has to take the current `velocity.x` into consideration, as in: `rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (Mathf.Clamp(rigidbody.velocity.x + (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * maxSpeed), 0f, terminalSpeed), rigidbody.velocity.y);`